# What software could I use to do video surveillance?

Tags: video, webcam, monitoring

I'm trying to set up a video surveillance system at home.

Is there a software system out there that is easy enough for a beginner/basic user of 12.04 to set up and use?

I've been attempting to set up *ZoneMinder* for a week and still cannot get the first image from even my webcam.

Answer (score 4):

I found an easy way with a webcam and thanks to this [french documentation](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/motion).
The idea is:

1. define a **service to synchronize** a folder on your PC and your Smart Phone
   *or to let you consult it from an other computer on Internet*:

   - install the synchronization service **on your PC**
   - install the synchronization service **on your smart phone** 
       *or do nothing and just use internet to consult the captured video from an other PC.*
2. install a **video software** to record videos when movement is detected

---

Let's do it with **DropBox** and **Motion**:

1. Install the **service to synchronize**: **Dropbox**

   - On your PC, install [DropBox [image: Install nautilus-dropbox]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-dropbox)
     follow the instruction and install with the default options 
     It will create a folder `/home/boris/Dropbox`  *(with boris your user logon)*
   - Install **DropBox on your smart phone**, depending on your Smart Phone, [find here the way to install it](https://www.dropbox.com/mobile).
     <sub>*I personally installed it from the GooglePlay on my Android phone. (without giving my phone number on the web site)*</sub>
2. Install [Motion [image: Install motion]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/motion) on your PC, and configure it:

   - copy the configuration file in your user environment:

     ```
     sudo cp /etc/motion/motion.conf ~/.config/motion.conf
     sudo chown boris:boris ~/.config/motion.conf
     ```

     *(replace boris by your user logon)*
   - edit the configuration file:

     ```
     gedit ~/.config/motion.conf
     ```

     modify the target directory to be **your dropbox directory**
     *(replace boris by your user logon)*
     [image]

     you may also want to define the resolution of the capture
     [image]
   - then launch your video surveillance:

     ```
     $ motion -c ~/.config/motion.conf
     ```

Answer (score 2):

I came through a best video surveillance software named as `xeoma`. Its having many features thats can made you wonder about it.

you can install it in ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install xeoma
```

for more information regarding features read [XEOMA](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xeoma/) .

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one more software named as  **gSpy**

gSpy : Its gnome eye used for secret cameras. you can download it from

http://gspy.sourceforge.net/

If you want to install it then , open your terminal and do as follows

```
wget http://gspy.sourceforge.net/gspy-0.1.8-src.tar.gz
   tar -xvf gspy-0.1.8-src.tar.gz
    cd gspy-0.1.8
    ./autogen.sh
    make
    sudo make install
```